nginx doubling the full domain when linking image assets in Laravel project
I've got a webserver running a Laravel (Statamic) website served with nginx. There is a CMS portion of this site that uses local storage to serve up images from the project folder. However, when the browser tries to pull those images, it fails (404 errors) for the assets only.

The request tab in my chrome dev console is showing that the URL for this asset is wrong. When I actually hit my server, the url looks like staging.site.com/staging.site.com/storage/images/image.png. I checked the URL in the HTML itself and it does not match that pattern, instead it looks like staging.site.com/storage/images/image.png (as expected). For some reason that I don't understand, it seems to be doubling the subdomain, domain, and TLD once it hits nginx (I think?).
Stuff I've Checked

Laravel's symbolic links are set; I've double checked by running php artisan storage:link, which confirmed it had already been run. The images are on the server, I can see them in the terminal when I SSH in and cd into the correct folder
If I manually remove the first domain chunk it renders the image, so the image is accessible on the server, it's just setting the URL wrong.
I checked my nginx and laravel logs on my server and I'm not seeing any error messages in either of them that look even remotely relevant

Extra info

I used certbot for SSL
Everything works as-expected in local development environments. The fact that this issue is only present on the server leads me to believe it's an nginx configuration issue
I don't think this is a ufw issue because I can access the file fine as long as the URL is correct

What in the world is going on here? Why is my domain getting duplicated?
nginx configs
nginx.conf
user username;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;        
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        client_max_body_size 50M;
}

laravel (sites-enabled)
server {
#    server_name _;
    server_name staging.site.com;
    root /var/www/site/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
    proxy_buffers   4 512k;
    proxy_buffer_size   256k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = staging.site.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name staging.site.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}


If you look at the source in the browser, is the link doubled there? This looks like it might be an asset linking issue, not an nginx/routing issue.

Now that I have stepped away and reapplied brain power, that makes sense. The URL is showing up in-full in the HTML, so staging.server.com/folders instead of just /folders

@aynber you nailed it; i needed to fix the way my project wass working with the filesystem. thank you so much ❤️

As @aynber pointed out in the comments, this is not actually an nginx issue. The issue was that my disk in my Laravel project was set up to literally inject that URL into the string.
The fix was to add the filesystem disk that comes with Statamic, but which I didn't have (because I went Laravel project->Statamic project).
<?php

// filesystems.php

return [
    // ...
    'disks' => [
        // ...
        'assets' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('assets'),
            'url' => '/assets',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
    ]
];

